# Dependency Injection, PHP and performance concerns

Tags: php, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have seen number of frameworks implement DI in php. However, since all objects in php get created and destroyed during the lifetime of a single request, I wonder how this affects performance.

Generally, you will define a number of objects inside a DI container. In php, even if a Controller does not need most of these objects, they will still be instantiated.
Also, if you declare your DI dependencies in a php file, you will load all referenced scripts. Without DI, you load only what you need.

I have seen some frameworks permit lazy DI, so this should help with unneeded instantiation. Maybe segmenting DI is also a way to address the first issue.
So, will DI adversely affect my php application performance and how should I go about implement DI in php so it does not happen?

Comment: Has your application reached the level where this extra overhead is actually causing issues? Or are you worrying about this before you've even written the first `<?php ?>` tag pair? Don't micro-optimize at the beginning.

Comment: Application suffers from performance problems and a part of the overhaul is refactoring the app, making it more modular, introducing di fwks, doctrine 2 etc. so it would be easier to maintain and optimize. I don't want this to introduce additional performance penalty.

Comment: I don't think deciding on a DI approach/framework is a micro-optimization. It's an application foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identify if there is a problem, and then what is the problem.

- Do you have dependencies that take a lot of resources and time to build?

You can use lazy-injection, something like:

```
class Class1 {
    /**
     * @Inject(lazy=true)
     * @var Class2
     */
    private $class2;

    public function doSomething() {
        // The dependency is loaded NOW
        return $this->class2->getSomethingElse();
    }
```

(example from [PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/))

- Do you have too many dependencies in your classes?

You have to ask yourself if dependency injection is really the problem. If you where creating new instances (or using Singletons) instead of using DI, would the problem go away? (I don't think so)

IMO performance considerations should come with a clear identification that DI is the problem. There are so many parts that can go wrong in an application.

Answer (score 0):

> Generally, you will define a number of objects inside a DI container. In php, even if a Controller does not need most of these objects, they will still be instantiated.

Well, there is also lazy initialization, so those objects are only lightweight placeholders and in case functionality is needed, the big object is created only when needed.

> So, will DI adversely affect my php application performance and how should I go about implement DI in php so it does not happen?

Every line of code affects application performance, so whatever you do, you need to deal with it. If you're really concerned about performance, you should start with caching the output of your application, so that there is no need to load any code unless you need to.